# How to load an integer value in an AVRO file to a date column in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I am referring to a similar post which i found very useful. It shows how we can load an integer column in an avro file to a BigQuery table containing a timestamp field.
[Compatibility of Avro dates and times with BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651878/compatibility-of-avro-dates-and-times-with-bigquery)

I have a similar question. Is there a way to load an integer value in an avro file to a date column in bigquery?

Since avro does not support date datatype, I have tried keeping the date as a string field in the avro and tried loading it into the date field in BigQuery.  But this does not work.

If i knew how BigQuery stores dates internally maybe i could try converting my date to that value and then load it to BQ.

Any suggestions how i can do this?

Comment: If you don't mind trying...what happens if you load an Avro file with integer values of, say, `1`, `2`, and `17311`? If that doesn't work, one option would be to have your table store the dates as type INT64 in days since the Unix epoch, then use the `DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE` function as part of a logical view.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. Here is the table i created. It has two columns. One date and one integer. My input file is a simple csv file containing 2 columns as "17167,1". I get the below error when i try to load this file into the table. bq load --format=csv rohan.temp_date dt.txt
- file-00000000: Could not parse '17167' as date for field dt
(position 0) starting at location 0

Comment: Last option is when i can try to load the date as a string and cast it as a date in the view.

Comment: I meant loading an Avro file containing those integer values, not a CSV file. If the Avro option doesn't work, then a logical view might be your best choice.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I tried loading in an Avro file, that had a type "int" into BigQuery from GCS, and got the following error - "Cannot read tablet : Incompatible types. 'day' : INT64 'day' : INT32". It doesn't seem to matter if the schema is defined as "int" or "long" in Avro, BigQuery seems to interpret it as an int64.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I think you will need to use Mosha's suggestion below of transforming the data after you load it into BigQuery unless Avro starts supporting a date type at some point.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to load integer column from Avro into `DATE` column in BigQuery directly. You can load Avro file into intermediate table which will have integer column, and then run SQL query which translates this integer into `DATE` using `DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE` function (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_from_unix_date)

Comment: are there any plans to fix this? This would make it much easier to normalize input to feed into BigQuery