# How to export AVRO files from a BigQuery table with a DATE column and load it again to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

For moving data from a BigQuery (BQ) table that resides in the US, I want to export the table to a Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket in the US, copy it to an EU bucket, and from there import it again.

The problem is that AVRO does not support `DATE` types, but it is crucial to us as we are using the new [partitioning feature](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions) that is not relying on ingestion time, but a column in the table itself.

The AVRO files contain the `DATE` column as a `STRING` and therefore a
`Field date has changed type from DATE to STRING` error is thrown, when trying to load the files via `bq load`.

There has been a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651878/compatibility-of-avro-dates-and-times-with-bigquery), but it is about timestamps - in my case it absolutely needs to be a `DATE` as dates don't carry timezone information and timestamps are always interpreted in UTC by BQ.

It works when using `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`, but is it possible to make this work with AVRO files?

Comment: Why do you have to use AVRO? If it works with NJSON, then why not just do  it that way? Or CSV.

Comment: AVRO includes a schema, JSON and CSV do not

Comment: Please see [the feature request for logical types](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905894). You can also sign up for the whitelist.

Comment: Awesome @ElliotBrossard !  I signed up to have the project whitelisted

Comment: Just specify the schema when you load it back in though. Is that a problem for you?

Comment: Yes it means I need to keep track of the source schema(-changes) and this is automatically included with AVRO.

Comment: But, it's a one off load/migration, correct? So, I don't quite understand what you mean by you need to track the source schema (-changes).

Comment: No it's not a one-off migration, I will be loading tables daily which schema can change at any time. The feature that @ElliottBrossard was so kind to enable for my project works flawlessly :)

Comment: Do we still need to be whitelisted for this feature?
I thought that Avro logical types was now GA.

With "bq load --use_avro_logical_types" I am able to get the correct types for "timestamp" or "numeric", but I still have an issue with the "date" column.
It seems like the issue is not on the "bq load" operation, but more on the "bq extract" that converts my "date" columns into some "Strings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ElliottBrossard pointed out in the comments, there's a public feature request regarding this where it's possible to sign up for the whitelist.